# Are there any international rules against firing ballistic missiles over other countries?

Tags: international-law, north-korea, borders, japan, space

The BBC [reports](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-63126534) that (for the 2nd time since 2017) "North Korea fires ballistic missile over Japan". The missile fell into the Pacific ocean.

I'm guessing there are some treaties on the maximum height national airspace extends to, otherwise countries (which do have [such ASAT capabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-satellite_weapon)) would be shooting down unfriendly spy satellites above their territory all the time.

So, what are the internationally accepted rules for ballistic missiles' trajectories?

Comment: I know from that BBC piece that North Korea is prohibited by a UNSC resolution from certain kinds of missile tests. I'm asking what the general rules would be, for other countries. The BBC also claims that "Flying missiles towards or over other countries without any warning or consultation also contravenes international norms." but doesn't get into details on those norms.

Comment: Regarding the height of national airspace, see here: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/43439/is-there-a-height-limit-to-national-airspace . The accepted answer is 5 years old, but still seems to apply.

Comment: @CharlieEvans: interesting. So apparently the USA and USSR not shooting down each other's spy sats was an unwritten "gentlemen's agreement" (which didn't extended to manned spy planes.)

Comment: My guess would be that North Korea is the only country in the world that does that without getting an agreement from the country overflown first and everywhere else this is handled the same way as military aircraft flying over a foreign country.

Comment: "otherwise countries ... would be shooting down" Not necessarily. Just because they would be allowed to do that (according to some rules), doesn't mean they have to do it all the time. They could simply tolerate it instead.

Comment: Seems a near-duplicate of [How high must a craft fly in order to not be in foreign airspace?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1527/how-high-must-a-craft-fly-in-order-to-not-be-in-foreign-airspace), unless there are specific rules for ballistic missiles that don't apply to other aircraft/space vehicles.

Comment: @StuartF: interestingly though, the response on the aviation stack (linked by Charlie Evans) and the one you linked to here differ rather substantially.

Comment: @StuartF: most countries have indeed signed up to the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_Space_Treaty (not mentioned on aviation stack) but it doesn't have hard boundaries AFAICT. So the matter of the issue of the flight seems to matter. Which is not exactly explored in either of the previous questions.

Comment: What do you mean by a “rule”? Firing a weapon over another country’s territory is a _casus belli_, and Japan would thus be justified in declaring war on North Korea, but probably doesn’t wish to do so.

Comment: Where could North Korea fire a ballistic missile that wouldn't go over another country? There seems to be only a small portion on the west cost that could shoot south and not be over a country depending on how far it goes.

Comment: @JoeW: have them land in the water short of Japan? Of course that would not let them test ICBMs that reach Japan and beyond (USA). But you seem to be taking it as a given that a country has a right to test ICBMs to their full range or something like that.

Comment: @Fizz I didn't say that they had a right, just asking a simple question of how most countries could be expected to test these sort of things and not fire over another country.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but wouldn't that be an invasion of sovereign air space?  And isn't that a violation of international law?

Comment: Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/23518/is-firing-an-icbm-legal

Answer (score 3):

Q: *Are there any international rules against firing ballistic missiles over other countries?*

Apparently not. There is, however, a consensus to talk more about the issue.

United Nations Office for Disarmament Affairs, [Missiles](https://disarmament.unoda.org/wmd/missiles/) —

> Currently, there is no legally binding multilateral instrument dealing with the issue of missiles.
>
> Pursuant to General Assembly resolutions, three Panels of Government Experts devoted to the issue of missiles have been established within the United Nations. The first Panel was established from July 2001 to July 2002, the second Panel in 2004 and the third Panel completed its work in June 2008, agreeing on its report by consensus. There has been no resolution introduced on the topic in the General Assembly since 2008 (resolution 63/55).

**A/63/176** [The issue of missiles in all its aspects](https://documents-dds-ny.un.org/doc/UNDOC/GEN/N08/440/92/PDF/N0844092.pdf?OpenElement) Report of the Secretary-General, 28 July 2008.

> The Panel concluded, among other things, that it was important to have continued international efforts to deal with the increasingly complex issue of missiles in the interest of international peace and security and to deliberate further on the issue, specifically focusing attention on existing and emerging areas of consensus. The Panel also emphasized the important role of the United Nations in providing a more structured and effective mechanism to build such a consensus.

Comment: UN doesn't seem to appreciate deep linking "you have reached this site through unauthorized means". Exact same link work when accessed from https://www.undocs.org/Home/Mobile?FinalSymbol=A%2F63%2F176&Language=E&DeviceType=Desktop&LangRequested=False

Comment: While not specifically about missiles, aren't there rules about invading the airspace of another county? If you can't fly an airplane or blimp over another country, surely you can't fly a missile over it.

Comment: @Barmar - An earlier [comment on the question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/75994/are-there-any-international-rules-against-firing-ballistic-missiles-over-other-c/81623?noredirect=1#comment319105_75994) points to [Is there a height limit to national airspace?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/43439). The accepted answer, in a quote, says, "There is no international agreement on the vertical limit of state sovereignty." That leaves it up to the other country to complain through appropriate channels or take other action.

Comment: @RickSmith I'm not very familiar with the details of ballistic missiles, but I assumed they flew much closer to airspace than outer space, so that fuzzy boundary wasn't an issue.

Comment: @Barmar - "..., the highest altitude (apogee) reached during free-flight is about 4,500 kilometers (2,800 mi)." -- [Ballistic missile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballistic_missile#Flight). This compares to 18 kilometers (11 miles) as the upper limit for aircraft (except SSTs and some spy planes).

Comment: I see. That does seem more like outer space. So unless it passes over another country during initial ascen, it's probably not covered by treaties. I didn't mention final descent because that's presumably the target, and different concerns apply.

Answer (score 1):

This is marginal information, but interestingly enough North Korea says (and Reuters [agrees](https://www.reuters.com/world/asia-pacific/how-north-korea-could-use-pacific-firing-range-perfect-its-missiles-2023-02-22/) with that) that their ICBM (but not necessarily other, e.g. IRBM) tests can be distinguished from actual attacks by the "lofted trajectory" their tests take. [E.g.](https://www.reuters.com/world/asia-pacific/north-korea-says-it-test-launched-hwasong-18-icbm-wednesday-yonhap-2023-07-12/) in July 2023:

> The Hwasong-18's 74-minute flight time was the longest ever for a North Korean missile test, KCNA said, adding the second and third stages were flown on a lofted trajectory to a high altitude for safety.
>
> "The test-fire had no negative effect on the security of the neighbouring countries," it said.

Or from an earlier reporting in Feb 2023:

> North Korea has never launched an ICBM on anything but a lofted trajectory, which sends missiles high into space rather than on the lower and longer flight paths that they would follow in real use.
>
> Pyongyang says it does this out of concern for the safety of its neighbours.

I'm not exactly sure if everyone else is convinced that attacks couldn't be purposefully launched like that.

Comment: This is interesting, but I don't think it answers the question you asked.  Also, given the speed of a rocket, and the unknown final altitude (which is unknown until the rocket has reached that altitude and begins descending), these statements make sense only *after* the fact.  In other words, while the rocket is being prepared for launch, and as it is being launched, it is likely difficult to detect exactly where it is headed and where it will impact.  Finally, keep in mind that rockets often deploy multiple warheads that land across a large area.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket: Largely I agree. It seems to be *modus vivendi* or ad-hoc rule that North Korea is proposing, but I'm not sure how much other countries are buying into it. The Reuters pieces don't mention any explicit reaction in that regard.

Comment: My perception is that North Korea knows that if any missile, intentionally or accidentally, lands in any other nation, the North Korean government & military will no longer exist.  Which does make me wonder why they persist on making missiles.  I think they hope it generates fear, but in reality I don't think it does.  I think all nations are aware of the consequences, and thus don't really care that much about North Korea's missile launches (except perhaps Japan because of the close proximity, population density of major cities, and perhaps residual trauma from WWII).